# Regex for the first 3 components of URI path

Tags: php, regex

Here's the URI path I need to parse:

tom-tom/sam/beta-forest%E2%84%A2/product-a

I need to extract just the first three components that end in a forward slash.

```
preg_match("/^([\w\/ %\.-]*){3}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

This almost gets me what I want but it excludes the '%E2%84%A2'. I've been rearranging things on http://www.phpliveregex.com/ but to no avail.

Note that if I try to just parse the complete URL, say mysite.com/tom-tom/sam/beta-forest%E2%84%A2/product-a, then this regex gets me what I want:

> preg_match("/^(https?://)?([\da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})([/\w
>   %.-]*){3}//", $path, $output_array);

I need to parse the URI path however and I need to include the % sign. Sigh..

Edit:

My expected output is:

```
tom-tom/sam/beta-forest%E2%84%A2/
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Maybe parse_url can be useful for you http://mx1.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @Alx http://regex101.com/r/rD4sO4/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must need to include the start pattern to get the first three components.

```
preg_match("/^(?:[^\/]*\/){3}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rD4sO4/2)

Comment: yep, but it's not a problem at all.

Comment: True, just ugly and messy but again user preference.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_match("~(?:[^/]+/){3}~", $input_line, $output_array);
```